# How do i make the browser display a pdf file instead of downloading it from Nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, npm, backend, pdfkit

This is my code. but it keeps downloading the file instead of downloading it.

````
  const fileName = 'file.pdf';
  const filePath = path.join('data', invoiceName);

  const pdfDoc = new PDFDocument();
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline');
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
  pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));
  pdfDoc.pipe(res);

  pdfDoc.fontSize(26).text('Hello')

  pdfDoc.end('');
  ```
````

Comment: Not all browsers can display PDFs.  You don't have much control over what a browser does with what you send it.

Comment: but i am using chrome. i thought chrome could do that?